# Upload a file from the external storage

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I need to find a "simple" way to upload a data file to my app.
My solution is for the user to connect to the phone and with a cable to upload the file to the "Download" folder.

Not that simple I agree. ;)

On top of that I need to request READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE which for the user triggers the message "Allow app to access photos, media and files on your device?". Definitely not nice as I don't want to scare people just for a file that they send me.

2 questions:

-do you have a smarter solution to make visible a file from an app?

-is there another permission more restrictive, just to read my file? on external storage?

Comment: MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL this can help to manage uploaded media. but no other efficient ways except that, what u have mentioned

Comment: :(  MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL still gives me a permission denied. only READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE works. it's pretty bad from Android?

Comment: Your story does not make sense. Nor your questions. Where is this about?

Comment: What does not make sense? If I am unclear, please let me know what part you don't understand? If my English is clear and you disagree with the issue, let me know how would you do what I describe?